# Disturbance Rejection in a Closed Loop Control System

Tags: signal, control-system

[image][image]

I was reading an article about disturbance rejection of closed loop control system and I came across the sentence "becomes almost zero, and the effect of the disturbance is suppressed."

I have also attached snapshot of article and highlighted the confusing part of sentence. I am not able to understand how closed loop transfer function of the disturbance accounted in the system becomes zero??

Comment: Please don't write in capital letters, it's regarded as if you were shouting.

Comment: Writing "reducing something to almost zero" doesn't mean much in my opinion. Example: *the noise is 1 uV which is almost zero* Sure, 1 uV is a small voltage but what if my signal is also 1 uV? In feedback systems usually the disturbances are reduced by the **excess loopgain**. I would just **ignore** the "almost zero" statement as it is **meaningless**.

Comment: Also please remove the capital letters in the title.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie For a transfer function (where the text is about) that reduces to zero, is definitely means something.

Comment: @Huisman Note "consider the case... the >> 1" that means that the transfer function will be zero only if the gain approaches **infinity**. It is more like a **limit function**. It never **really** becomes zero. But feel free to prove me wrong :-)

Comment: In the upper equation the denominator is 1 + G1*G2*H. When G1*G2*H >> 1 you can approach 1 + G1*G2*H by G1*G2*H (like you can approach 100001 by 10000). You can apply this to the whole tranfer function.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I thought: If the signal is the order of uV and the noise also in the order of uV (as your first comment) and the closed-loop transfer C/D is 1/1000000 (almost zero) than the noise is negligible. Would the noise be in the order of volts, then it is not negligible. But I might be wrong as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In control systems the loop gain LG (product of all transfer functions within the closed loop) is a very important parameter.

In your case, the loop gain is **LG(s)=G1(s)*G2(s)*H(s)**.

As you can see, the closed-loop transfer function for the disturbed input

**Hd(s)=Cd(s)/D(s)=G2(s)/[1+LG(s)]**

will be rather small ("almost zero" in the text) for a large loop gain LG(s)>>1.

For the reference input the situation is different because the product G1(s)*G2(s) appears also in the numerator of the closed-loop function Hr(s)=Cr(s)/R(s).

With other words: Both closed-loop functions have the same denominator (1+LG) - however, the numerator for the closed-loop reference function (G1*G2) is larger than for the closed-loop disturbance function (G2). Hence, the influence of the disturbance signal is smaller if compared with the reference signal.

Answer (score 1):

Assume there's an integrator somewhere in the system, so that \$ G_1(s)G_2(s)H(s)=\large\frac{A(s)}{sB(s)}\$ where \$A(s)\$ and \$B(s)\$ are polynomials without a free \$s\$ term.

Now Set \$\small R(s)=0\$, and work out the CLTF: \$G(s)=\frac{C(s)}{D(s)}=\frac{sB(s)}{A(s)+sB(s)}\$. The DC gain is found by setting \$s=0\$, thus \$G(0)=0\$.

This means that disturbance will have no effect on the response once once the transients have decayed to zero. We say that the disturbance is rejected (but not instantaneously!)

Comment: @Chu....of course, I agree (theoretically).  However, this is true only if there would be an IDEAL integrator which - however - cannot be realized. Hence, the disturbance cannot be fully rejected.

Comment: @lvw , of course, nothing’s ideal. That’s life.